# Problems passing arguments with callNextMethod() in R

Tags: oop, r, methods, argument-passing, r-s4

### **My question:**

Why is `callNextMethod()` not passing arguments as expected to the next method?

### Situation:

Say I have two hierarchical classes `foo` and `bar` (`bar` is subclass of `foo`) for which I have a method `foobar` that can dispatch for both classes (i.e., has methods for both classes).

Furthermore, the method for the (sub)class `bar` calls the method for `foo` after some calculations with `callNextMethod()`.

Both methods have the same additional argument (with default) that should be passed to the method for `foo`, where only it is relevant.

```
setClass("foo", representation(x = "numeric"))
setClass("bar", contains = "foo")

setGeneric("foobar", function(object, ...) standardGeneric("foobar"))

setMethod("foobar", "foo", function(object, another.argument = FALSE, ...) {
    print(paste("in foo-method:", another.argument))
    if (another.argument) object@x^3
    else object@x^2
})

setMethod("foobar", "bar", function(object, another.argument = FALSE, ...) {
    print(paste("in bar-method:", another.argument))
     object@x <- sqrt(object@x)
    callNextMethod()
})
```

**Problem description:**
The arguments are not passed as expected, but the default values are taken from the method definition. Specifically, in the first method the argument is as specified in the call (`TRUE`), however, it changes to `FALSE` in the next method.

```
o1 <- new("bar", x = 4)

foobar(o1, another.argument = TRUE)
```

gives

```
[1] "in bar-method: TRUE"
[1] "in foo-method: FALSE"
[1] 4
```

I want the `another.argument` to be passed to the next method so that it is `TRUE` in the call to the `foo` method, too.

---

From `?callNextMethod` I get that it should work as expected (i.e., the named argument is passed as it is in the call):

> For a formal argument, say x, that appears in the original call, there
> is a corresponding argument in the next method call equivalent to x =
> x. In effect, this means that the next method sees the same actual
> arguments, but arguments are evaluated only once.

---

**My second question**: How can I pass another.argument to the next method. (I would really like to keep default arguments in both methods)

Comment: I'm stumped.  If you don't get any answers here you might try this on the `r-devel` mailing list ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this has to do with the way a method with a signature different from the generic is defined (within a function .local)

```
> selectMethod(foobar, "bar")
Method Definition:

function (object, ...) 
{
    .local <- function (object, another.argument = FALSE, ...) 
    {
        print(paste("in bar-method:", another.argument))
        object@x <- sqrt(object@x)
        callNextMethod()
    }
    .local(object, ...)
}

Signatures:
        object
target  "bar" 

defined "bar"
```

The work-around is to either define the generic and methods to have the same signature

```
setGeneric("foobar",
    function(object, another.argument=FALSE, ...) standardGeneric("foobar"),
    signature="object")
```

or pass the arguments explicitly to `callNextMethod`

```
setMethod("foobar", "bar", function(object, another.argument = FALSE, ...) {
    print(paste("in bar-method:", another.argument))
     object@x <- sqrt(object@x)
    callNextMethod(object, another.argument, ...)
})
```

Comment: Another great answer from you to a S4 question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks. Why can't we just call it a bug rather than an "infelicity" or an "indiscretion" ... ? Since it's hurting my brain to try to figure out how the observed behavior does **not** contradict what's in the documentation?  (S4 hurts my brain at the best of times.)

Comment: I fully agree (not with the part on S4 hurting the brain, though. I actually like S4).

Comment: 'bug' implies some unintentional oversight, and I don't have that insight into the author's brain. So I've removed the judgement entirely. I'd encourage a report on R-devel, otherwise the person able to change this is ignorant of the problem.

Comment: I second the suggestion of an R-devel report. IMHO this *is* a bug, because I can't think of any plausible interpretation of the documentation that is consistent with the behavior of the code.  (That said, one could fix the bug by changing the documentation ...)

Comment: I wrote a message to R-devel about it yesterday (http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/28806), but no answers so far. I will keep you informed if there are news.