# S4 class [ (subset) inheritance with additional arguments

Tags: r, inheritance, r-s4

This is an extension of [Using callNextMethod() within accessor function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24875284/2752888).

Update 2017-03-25: To illustrate how this only fails when loading the methods, but not when it's in a built package, I created a dummy package: https://github.com/zkamvar/inheritest#readme

#### Basic problem:

I have a class bar that inherits another class foo, and both of them have additional arguments for the [ method. The method for foo works consistently, but the method for bar fails after the first use.

#### Error and Traceback:

```
Error in callNextMethod(x, i, j, ..., drop): bad object found as method (class "function")

4: stop(gettextf("bad object found as method (class %s)",  dQuote(class(method))), 
   domain = NA)
3: callNextMethod(x, i, j, ..., drop) at #9
2: .local(x, i, j, ..., drop = drop)
1: BAR["x"]
```

#### Further details:

I have a package that implements a class that depends on a class from another package. When the packages are built, everything works fine, but when my package is simply loaded (using `devtools::load_all(".")`), I get the behavior below.

#### Minimum Working Example:

```r
foo <- setClass("foo", representation(x = "numeric", y = "numeric"))
bar <- setClass("bar", representation(distance = "numeric"), contains = "foo")

setMethod(f = "[", signature = signature(x = "foo", i = "ANY", j = "ANY", drop = "ANY"), 
  definition = function(x, i, j, ..., foo = TRUE, drop = FALSE) {
    if (foo) 
      message("FOOOOOOO")
    if (i == "x") {
      return(x@x)
    } else {
      if (i == "y") {
        return(x@y)
      }
    }
  })
#> [1] "["

setMethod(f = "[", signature = signature(x = "bar", i = "ANY", j = "ANY", drop = "ANY"), 
  definition = function(x, i, j, ..., bar = TRUE, drop = FALSE) {
    if (bar) 
      message("BAAAAAAR")
    if (i == "distance") {
      return(x@distance)
    } else {
      callNextMethod(x, i, j, ..., drop)
    }
  })
#> [1] "["

FOO <- new("foo", x = 1, y = 4)
BAR <- new("bar", x = 1, y = 4, distance = 3)
FOO["x"]
#> FOOOOOOO
#> [1] 1
BAR["x"]
#> BAAAAAAR
#> FOOOOOOO
#> [1] 1
FOO["x"]
#> FOOOOOOO
#> [1] 1
BAR["distance"]
#> BAAAAAAR
#> [1] 3
BAR["x"]  # fails
#> BAAAAAAR
#> Error in callNextMethod(x, i, j, ..., drop): bad object found as method (class "function")
BAR["x", foo = FALSE]
#> BAAAAAAR
#> [1] 1
```

Note: when I passed this through [reprex](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=reprex), The first and last calls to BAR resulted in errors as well, but I am showing what I experience in an interactive session. I am using R version 3.3.3

Comment: I find the first call to `BAR['x']` fails in an ordinary interactive session. Debugging callNextMethod might help, but I struggle with S4 methods. What seems to be happening is that the `bar` method is not getting recognized as a method in callNextMethod. But why this happens... mmph.

Comment: The reprex also had `BAR['x']` failing... and it now fails in my session... nevertheless, it's still weird.

Comment: @dash2 it happens because for some reason R adds an extra layer to the callstack when the method provided for `[` has extra arguments. If you `debug(callNextMethod)`, look at the result of `maybeMethod <- sys.function(parent)` and then try `maybeMethod <- sys.function(parent - 1)`. The actual method definition is one step up, and possibly this is a side effect of S4 for primitives piggy-backing S3 under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `callNextMethod()` is not smart enough to handle methods on primitives with augmented formals. I've fixed it and will commit to trunk soon.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any reason why this only failed when the code is loaded interactively as opposed to within a package (example: https://github.com/zkamvar/inheritest#readme)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer: it is to do with "[" specifically. Here is some working code, that replaces the '[' method with a 'bat' method. It works fine for me:

```
foo <- setClass("foo", representation(x = "numeric", y = "numeric"))
bar <- setClass("bar", representation(distance = "numeric"), contains = "foo")

bat <- function (x, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE) message('in bat')
setGeneric('bat')
setMethod(f = "bat", signature = signature(x = "foo"), 
  definition = function(x, i, j, ..., foo = TRUE, drop = FALSE) {
    if (foo) 
      message("FOOOOOOO")
    if (i == "x") {
      return(x@x)
    } else {
      if (i == "y") {
        return(x@y)
      }
    }
  })
#> [1] "["

setMethod(f = "bat", signature = signature(x = "bar"), 
  definition = function(x, i, j, ..., bar = TRUE, drop = FALSE) {
    if (bar) 
      message("BAAAAAAR")
    if (i == "distance") {
      return(x@distance)
    } else {
      callNextMethod(x, i, j, ..., drop)
    }
  })

FOO <- new("foo", x = 1, y = 4)
BAR <- new("bar", x = 1, y = 4, distance = 3)
bat(FOO, 'x')
bat(BAR, 'distance')
bat(BAR, 'x')
```

And now:

```
bat(FOO, 'x')
FOOOOOOO
[1] 1
bat(BAR, 'x')
BAAAAAAR
FOOOOOOO
[1] 1
bat(BAR, 'distance')
BAAAAAAR
[1] 3
bat(BAR, 'x')
BAAAAAAR
FOOOOOOO
[1] 1
```

So, I think this is something to do with the interaction of S4 dispatch and ['s own dispatching... and solutions? I have none, except to avoid S4 like the plague it seems to be. Maybe R-devel can help. It's possible this is a genuine R bug, given that the code only breaks for `[`.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. I'm wondering if a solution might be to create a dummy method, and use that internally for `[`. I'm just afraid that if it is a bug in `[`, it might be on the side that `[` should never have had arguments added :/

Answer (score 1):

The issue has likely to do with the fact that `[` is a primitive, and primitives are dealt with differently when using `S4`. Digging into `callNextMethod` shows that the callstack isn't analyzed correctly in the case that the method has different arguments compared to the generic for that primitive function. If you drop the argument `bar` from the method definition, dispatching works correctly.

That said, there is another workaround that doesn't require you to choose another function name. I add an extra function `as.foo` and recall the generic after converting to a foo object:

```
setGeneric("as.foo", function(x)standardGeneric("as.foo"))
setMethod("as.foo", signature = "bar",
          function(x)
            new("foo", x = x@x, y = x@y))

setMethod(f = "[", signature = signature(x = "bar", i = "ANY", j = "ANY", drop = "ANY"), 
          definition = function(x, i, j, ..., bar = TRUE, drop = FALSE) {
            if (bar) 
              message("BAAAAAAR")
            if (i == "distance") {
              return(x@distance)
            } else {
               x <- as.foo(x)
               callGeneric()
            }
          }
)
```

This way you circumvent the hiccup in dispatching, and all the code that used to fail now works

```
FOO["x"]
#> FOOOOOOO
#> [1] 1
BAR["x"]
#> BAAAAAAR
#> FOOOOOOO
#> [1] 1
BAR["distance"]
#> BAAAAAAR
#> [1] 3
BAR["x"]  
#> BAAAAAAR
#> FOOOOOOO
#> [1] 1
BAR["x", foo = FALSE]
#> BAAAAAAR
#> [1] 1
```

Comment: This indeed sounds like a bug in R S4, have you reported it?

Comment: @dash2 Well, I'm not 100% sure it's a bug or a "feature". It might be somewhere deep in the manuals there's an explanation for all this. I do know that S4 in the case of primitive functions are a special case, and I personally wouldn't add extra arguments to a method for `[`. I was going to dig deeper into this and post on R-devel, but I want to investigate a bit further to make sure I won't get my arse handed back to me with the label "stupid" :-) In any case, using `callGeneric` works.

Comment: @dash2 Michael is ahead of us, this has been taken care of already .