# how to setMethod `[` for a S4 object to be applied to a data.table in a slot

Tags: r, indexing, data.table, r-s4

I would like to be able to apply the "subset" (bracket) `[` method on a S4 object let's call it `foo` in such a way that when it is called `setMethod("[", 'foo', ...` it will apply the `[` operator on the data.table it holds in a specific slot.
Example:

```
foo <- setClass("foo", slots = c(myDT = "data.table"),  
                   prototype = prototype( myDT = NULL ))
# quickly make a foo class with a DT in the myDT slot 
myfoo <- new("foo", myDT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9))
# sneak peek
myfoo
An object of class "foo"
Slot "myDT":
   x y v
1: b 1 1
2: b 3 2
3: b 6 3
4: a 1 4
5: a 3 5
6: a 6 6
7: c 1 7
8: c 3 8
9: c 6 9
```

The tricky part

```
# I want to be able to do eg 
myfoo[1:3, 2:3]
   y v
1: 1 1
2: 3 2
3: 6 3
```

and have it give me the same result as if doing:

```
myfoo@myDT[1:3, 2:3]
   y v
1: 1 1
2: 3 2
3: 6 3
```

So far (I am guessing) it will/should be something along the lines of

```
setMethod(f = "[", signature = signature(x = "foo"),
                    definition = function(x, ...) {
                      `[`(x@.myDT, ...)
                    # OR maybe 
                    # x <- x@myDT  
                    # callNextMethod(x, ...)
                 }

)
```

But whatever I call `myfoo[i,j]` with it wll always just return the whole data.table.

Any ideas if this can be accomplished? So far I am stuck usually on errors about `j` not fitting the bill.
And I would like to avoid having to fully implement some form of shadow-indexing for this slot if I can somehow "recycle" what is available in `data.table` already;
of course also with the added benefit of the other `data.table` functions maybe also being applicable this way?
But for a beginning "passing on" indices would be a good start.

PS: If you wonder why not just do `myfoo@myDT` - the real life `foo` class has multiple slots of which only one (the `data.table` one) is "worthy" to be indexed and so I want to "shortcut" that methods application a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a late, not-so-hacky answer:

```r
library(data.table)
setClass("Foo", slots = c(dt = "data.table"), prototype = list(dt = data.table()))
setMethod("[", signature(x = "Foo", i = "ANY", j = "ANY", drop = "ANY"),
          function(x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) {
              if (missing(j))
                  callGeneric(x@dt, i, , ..., with = TRUE)
              else callGeneric(x@dt, i, j, ..., with = FALSE)
          })

foo <- new("Foo", dt = data.table(x = letters[1:6], y = 1:6, z = rnorm(6L)))
identical(foo[1:3, 2:3], foo@dt[1:3, 2:3]) # TRUE
```

This method still does not support the main features of `[.data.table` for the reason outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593102) question, namely that `i` and `j` must be evaluated in addition to `x` before multiple dispatch (a feature of S4, not S3) can occur.  Hence:

```r
foo@dt[y >= 3L]
##    x y           z
## 1: c 3  0.02991911
## 2: d 4 -0.36919712
## 3: e 5 -0.03291414
## 4: f 6 -1.02399695

foo[y >= 3L]
## Error in `[.data.table`(x@dt, i, , with = TRUE, ...) :
##   i is not found in calling scope and it is not a column name either. When the first argument inside DT[...] is a single symbol (e.g. DT[var]), data.table looks for var in calling scope.
```

You *can* still use variables in your environment as index vectors:

```r
ii <- 3:6
foo[ii]
##    x y           z
## 1: c 3  0.02991911
## 2: d 4 -0.36919712
## 3: e 5 -0.03291414
## 4: f 6 -1.02399695
```

Anyway, I agree with the comments suggesting that it is often better to implement classes built around `data.table` in S3.

Comment: you can get `foo[y >= 3L]` to work if you use this code `setMethod("[", signature(x = "Foo", i = "ANY", j = "ANY", drop = "ANY"), function(x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) {args <- as.list(match.call()[-1]) ; args[["x"]] <- quote(x@dt) ; do.call(callGeneric, args)}) ; foo[y >= 3L] # works`. I think due to `[` dispatch in C code, it doesn't follow the normal S4 requirement that all arguments in signature must be evaluated to be S4 dispatch.

Comment: @HieuNguyen That is shocking and potentially a bug in S4. OP should know about it but maybe not rely on it ... still, very cool ...

Comment: @HieuNguyen I investigated a bit ... `i` _is_ evaluated if there is any dispatch ambiguity requiring its evaluation (e.g., if we also define a method identical to yours but with `i = "logical"` in the signature).

Answer (score 1):

If you created the `foo` class, is it "a data table with a few things tacked on"? If so, then consider redefining your class to extend the data class:

```
setClass("foo",slots=list(
    ##other slots besides data table
),contains="data.table") -> foo
```

Then any method defined for a data table will work for this (use `x@.Data` to get at the "data table part" of `foo` object `x` if you need to).

If not, then you can still define your own method to act on another slot, as follows:

```
setMethod("[",
  signature(x="foo",i="ANY",j="ANY"),
  def=function(x,i,j) x@myDT[i,j]
)
```

the reason this may not have worked before is that you didn't include `i` and `j` in the method signature. You may also need to define a method for signature `x="foo",i="ANY",j="missing"` to cover the case when `j` isn't specified at all.

Comment: it is quite the opposite it is basically more similar to a list with various objects of which one slot happens to be a `data.table`;  some of the slots hold reference pointers, etc. 
so far the below solution is imo the shortest one, since I hoped to avoid defining specific cases of i, j, by, ... etc.

Comment: this looks promising but the column names etc get lost in the inheritance (`contains`) setting; do you know if there is maybe some `setattr` way around this?

Comment: strange --- if it's needed then I would write a method for `as` (using the `setAs` function) which explicitly sets the column names. Make sure you don't have a slot in the class called `colnames` or `dimnames`, that might mess things up if you do.

Comment: I decided to go back and reimplemented everything based on S3 - with `attributes` instead of S4 `slots`; "inheriting" the whole `data.table` functionality was way easier and went a lot smoother that way - thanks a lot for your input and assistance; I definitely learned that it is a bad idea to mix S3 and S4 with/for `data.table` that way

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve above task (by borrowing ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43069585/1216790)).
Feels a bit "hacky" but maybe someone will still jump in (later) with a more elegant solution.

```
fooDT <- setClass("fooDT", contains = "data.table")

setGeneric("as.fooDT", function(x) standardGeneric("as.fooDT"))
setMethod("as.fooDT", signature = "foo",
          function(x) new("fooDT", x@.myDT)
)

setMethod(f = "[", signature = signature(x = "foo"),
          definition = function(x, ...) {
              x <- as.fooDT(x)
              callGeneric()
            }
)
```