# R how to accesses to the data associated to a list of S4 class

Tags: bioinformatics, r-s4

I’m traying to create a S4 object, with a list and data.frame, the list contains sequences in Biostrings (AAStringSet or DNAStringSet) format, this is the code:

```
setClass(Class='myclass', 
    representation(
        mytable     = 'data.frame',
        sequences   = 'list'
))
```

table,  assignment table methods

```
setGeneric('mytable', function(x) standardGeneric('mytable'))
setMethod('mytable', 'myclass', function(x) { x@mytable })


setGeneric("mytable<-", function(x, value) standardGeneric("mytable<-"))
setMethod("mytable<-", "myclass", function(x, value) {
  x@mytable <- value
  return(x)
})
```

seq,  assignment-methods

```
setGeneric('seq', function(x) standardGeneric('seq'))
setMethod('seq', 'myclass', function(x) { x@sequences })


setGeneric("seq<-", function(x, value) standardGeneric("seq<-"))
setMethod("seq<-", "myclass", function(x, value) {
  x@sequences <- value
  return(x)
})
```

The data.frame

```
df[40:45, ]

                   sseqid gene
40 VFG007051(gi:27364316) epsM
41 VFG007052(gi:37678407) epsM
42 VFG007057(gi:27364317) epsL
43 VFG007063(gi:27364318) epsK
44 VFG007064(gi:37678405) epsK
45 VFG007069(gi:27364319) epsJ
```

the sequences list

```
sequences_list

$`sample-1`
AAStringSet object of length 141:
      width seq                                                                                         names               
  [1]   741 MSYDLDEDILQDFLIEAGEILELLSEQLVELENNPEDRDLLNAI...IKPLDNLLQGTPGMAGATITSDGHIALILDVPDLLKQYAAASRL DJCA_01737
  ...   ... ...
  [23]  723 MTTPQNRSSVDNSSDEIDLGKLLGILLDAKWIILVTTFLFAVGG...VARSRFEQAGIEVKGVILNAIEKKASSSYGYGYYNYSYGESNKA DJCA_03821

$`sample-2`
AAStringSet object of length 141:
      width seq                                                                                         names               
  [1]   741 MSYDLDEDILQDFLIEAGEILELLSEQLVELENNPEDRDLLNAI...IKPLDNLLQGTPGMAGATITSDGHIALILDVPDLLKQYAAASRL EKPI_01584
  ...   ... ...
  [37]  471 MKKITLFTLSLLATAVQVGAQEYVPIVEKPIYITSSKIKCVLHT...ISRYVDGNNTRYLLNIVGGRNVQVTPENEATQARWKPTLQQVKL EKPI_00335


$`sample-3`
AAStringSet object of length 143:
      width seq                                                                                         names               
  [1]   741 MSYDLDEDILQDFLIEAGEILELLSEQLVELENNPEDRDLLNAI...IKPLDNLLQGTPGMAGATITSDGHIALILDVPDLLKQYAAASRL BGDK_02838
  ...   ... ...
  [39]  388 MRITVVGAGYVGLANAALLAQYHSITLLDVDSKRVEQINAQSSP...FHSRVIKDLNEFKQTADVIVSNRMVEELTDVADKVYTRDLFGSD BGDK_04023
```

create the new object-myclass

```
x <- new("myclass", mytable=df, sequences=sequences_list)
```

Due to x@sequences is a list, I have to use [[]], my question is how to create an easy accesses to a list data?

to print all the list (in list format)

```
seq(x)

seq(x) %>% class()
[1] "list"
or
seq(x)["sample-1"] %>% class()
[1] "list"
```

If I want to extract in AAStringSet format, I have to use [[]]

```
seq(x)[["sample-1"]] %>% class()
[1] "AAStringSet"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Biostrings"

seq(x)[["sample-1"]]
AAStringSet object of length 141:
      width seq                                                                        names               
  [1]   741 MSYDLDEDILQDFLIEAGEILELLSEQLVELENNPE...GTPGMAGATITSDGHIALILDVPDLLKQYAAASRL DJCA_01737
  ...   ... ...
[141]   723 MTTPQNRSSVDNSSDEIDLGKLLGILLDAKWIILVT...GIEVKGVILNAIEKKASSSYGYGYYNYSYGESNKA DJCA_03821
```

it accesses to the sequences associated to sample-1 in  Biostrings format (AAStringSet in this example), for me it is ok, but I just want to accesses something easy, maybe just a pair of brackets and extract in AAStringSet format, and have the same result as seq(x)[["sample-1"]], something like:

```
seq(x)["sample-1"]
```

so what do you recommend me, just use the double bracket [[]], just like a list, or how to accesses with a single bracket [] and extract in AAStringSet format ???

Comment: is there a reason your class cannot `contain` the class `data.table`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73169345/how-to-setmethod-for-a-s4-object-to-be-applied-to-a-data-table-in-a-slot/73170826#73170826