# How to use callNextMethod

Tags: r, r-s4

Maybe due to language barrier, I am not quite sure about how/when to use `callNextMethod` even after reading documents. I think it is for passing arguments, but sometimes I see a R script with only one method still uses `callNextMethod`. I am confused.

Can anyone explain it in a more explicit way? Better with examples.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7190697/3358272

Comment: Also might be useful: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html